# How can I parse Jade templates with PHP, without other dependencies?

Tags: php, html, templates, pug

Given some Jade templates:

**base.jade**

```
div.container
    block content
```

**home.jade**

```
extends base
block content
    p Hello World
```

I want to be able to simply use `require` to call a component to render them using PHP, for example:

**index.php**

```
<?php
    require_once 'jadeParser.php';
    renderJade('home.jade');
?>
```

**output**

```
<div class="container">
    <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

https://github.com/everzet/jade.php seems like a solution, how can I use it without installing Symfony?

I can't configure the server I'm working on, I can't install things via Composer or .phar files. All I can do is add .php files via manual upload.

Is there any solution as simple as the one above?